# Google-Drive Auto-Sync on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-drive

How can I auto-sync my files from Google Drive and make them in a Google-Drive folder whenever a new file added/removed it would update the changes rather than downloading the whole Google Drive from scratch whenever I try to access it.

I have used the native Google Drive app on my Windows and MacOS devices and they worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [insync](https://www.insynchq.com/). It woks pretty well, but it's non-free.